# Вращение или поворот изображения при наведении

Tags: html, css, css3, анимация, hover

Я хочу узнать, как сделать вращающееся  изображение, когда на него наводится курсор.
Хотелось бы понять, как реализовать эту функциональность с помощью CSS и следующего кода:

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/3DWAbmN.jpg" />
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Spin or rotate an image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23695090/7394871) от участника  [@user3597950](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597950/user3597950).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23695090/564240

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы можете использовать **`transitions` `CSS3`** для вращения изображения при наведении.

### Rotating image :

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/3DWAbmN.jpg" />
```

Ещё пример:

*Вращение спирали*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLkKe.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
```

### Дополнительная информация и ссылки:

- Руководство по `transitions` CSS на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)
- Руководство по `transforms` CSS на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
- Таблица поддержки браузера для `2d-transforms` на [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)
- Таблица поддержки браузера для `transitions` на [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23695194/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Comment: `-webkit` уже можно не писать.

Comment: @Qwertiy этот ответ уже отметили, как дубликат с твоим постом http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499107/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8-y-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8, но ведь ничего общего нет, кроме слова "вращение" У тебя два текстовых блока, которые подменяют друг друга при вращении вокруг "Y", а у меня в ответе один образ, который вращается вокруг оси "Z"

Comment: @Alexandr_T, если ты был не согласен что это дубликатом, не надо было соглашаться

Answer (score 3):

```css
@keyframes _img {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg) translateZ(60px) rotateX(360deg);
    transform: rotateX(-360deg) translateZ(60px) rotateX(360deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px hsla(240, 80%, 50%, 1));
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px hsla(240, 80%, 50%, 1));
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px hsla(240, 80%, 50%, 1));
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px hsla(240, 80%, 50%, 1));
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(60px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(60px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

div {
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(20vw);
  height: calc(20vw);
  margin: 0% auto;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1);
  box-shadow: inset .75em .75em .75em hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1), inset -.75em -.75em .75em hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
  perspective: 300px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s linear 0s;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1);
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(8vw);
  height: calc(8vw);
  top: calc(100%/3 - 3%);
  left: calc(100%/3 - 4%);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px hsla(70, 80%, 40%, 1));
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(60px) rotateX(0deg);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px hsla(70, 80%, 40%, 1));
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(60px) rotateX(0deg);
}

div:hover img {
  animation: _img 3s 0s linear;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3DWAbmN.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: у вас не красивое решение , смотрите как ведёт img после hover у автора -ответчика и как происходит выход из hover в вашем случае

Comment: Не путайте вращающееся изображение с поворотом...

Comment: По крайней мере выше ответ красивее