# Анимация вращения кнопки при наведении

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qpushbutton, qtransform

Имеется кнопка и я хочу сделать так, чтобы при наведении кнопка вращалась (по-часовой), а при отведении с нее против часовой.

Вот что имеется:

[image: что имеется]

код:

```py
        self.settingsButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.settingsButton.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/settingsButton.png"))
        self.settingsButton.setToolTip("Настройки")
        self.settingsButton.setIconSize(QSize(35, 35))
        self.settingsButton.setStyleSheet(get_invisible_settingsButton_StyleSheet())
        self.settingsButton.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.settingsButton.clicked.connect(self.showSettingsWindow)
```

```py
    def showSettingsWindow(self):
        self.settings = SettingsWindow()
        self.settings.move(
            self.x() + self.width() // 2 - self.settings.width() // 2,
            self.y() + self.height() // 2 - self.settings.height() // 2,
        )
        self.settings.show()
```

```py
def get_invisible_settingsButton_StyleSheet():
    """ Прозрачная кнопка настроек """

    return """
        QPushButton {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        }

        QPushButton:hover {
            border-radius: 22px;
            background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 40);
        }

        QPushButton:pressed {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 70);
        }
    """
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.angle = 0 
        self.val = 0
        self.i = 0
        
        self.image_fname = ('back.png')      # установите небольшое изображение                       
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()                
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.image_fname))    
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 80))  
        
        self.pushButton.installEventFilter(self)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda : self.onRotate(self.val)) 
        
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.pushButton is obj:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
                self.val = 1
                self.timer.start(200)
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
                self.val = -1
        return super(Widget, self).eventFilter(obj, event)        

    def onRotate(self, val=0):
        self.i += val
        self.angle += 90 * val 
        t = QtGui.QTransform().rotate(self.angle)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap(self.image_fname).transformed(t)
        image_rotated = f'{os.path.splitext(self.image_fname)[0]}_rotated.png'
        pix.save(image_rotated)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(image_rotated)) 
        
        if not self.i: 
            self.timer.stop()


Stylesheet = '''
#pushButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width:  96px;
    max-width:  96px;
    min-height: 96px;
    max-height: 96px;
    border-radius: 48px;        
    border: 0px solid #09009B;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#pushButton:hover:pressed {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;    
}
#pushButton:hover {
    background-color: #0ff;
    border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(200, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**back.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**

> мне нужна плавная анимация. И еще, чтобы она после того, как на нее навели курсором и она повернулась на **`90`** градусов, перестала вращение. А когда курсор сместили с кнопки. А она так же плавно вернулась в исходное положение

Хотя я таких подробностей не вычитал в вашем вопросе, но я немного изменил пример, попробуйте.

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.angle = 0 
        self.val = 0
        self.i = 0
        
        self.image_fname = ('back.png')           # установите небольшое изображение                       
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()                
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.image_fname))    
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 80))  
        
        self.pushButton.installEventFilter(self)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda : self.onRotate(self.val)) 
        
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.pushButton is obj:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
                self.val = 1
                self.timer.start(100)
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
                self.val = -1
                self.timer.start(100)
        return super(Widget, self).eventFilter(obj, event)        

    def onRotate(self, val=0):
        self.i += val
        self.angle += 45 * val 
        if self.angle <= 90 and self.angle >= -90:
            t = QtGui.QTransform().rotate(self.angle)
            pix = QtGui.QPixmap(self.image_fname).transformed(t)
            image_rotated = f'{os.path.splitext(self.image_fname)[0]}_rotated.png'
            pix.save(image_rotated)
            self.pushButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(image_rotated)) 
        else: 
            self.timer.stop()


Stylesheet = '''
#pushButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width:  96px;
    max-width:  96px;
    min-height: 96px;
    max-height: 96px;
    border-radius: 48px;        
    border: 0px solid #09009B;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#pushButton:hover:pressed {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;    
}
#pushButton:hover {
    background-color: #0ff;
    border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(200, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @s-nick, мне нужна плавная анимация. И еще, чтобы она после того, как на нее навели курсором и она повернулась на 90 градусов, перестала вращение. А когда курсор сместили с кнопки. А она так же плавно вернулась в исходное положение. [примерно как тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640048/Вращение-или-поворот-изображения-при-наведении). Только мне нужно так сделать в PyQt5

Comment: @SkyGuy  Хотя я таких подробностей не вычитал в вашем вопросе, но я немного изменил пример, попробуйте.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour